# What are some physical or mathematical conecepts/techniques that can be used to "easily" do numerical experiments/analyses in physics?

Tags: computational-physics, experimental-technique

Basically I'm asking for concepts/techniques (don't know if it's the right word) that can be used/applied "easily" to eg. a physical system. It might be used to identify a behavior or a specific value of something.

One example would be the use of the Lyapunov exponent in order to identify chaos in a system.

Comment: That’s too broad and too vague a question. Can you be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: Most of physics is experiment to find numbers or how systems work, you're going to have to greatly narrow your focus.

Comment: Are you interested in fractals, in general?

Comment: Here I calculate the Lyapunov exponent for a Mandelbrot set — https://github.com/sjhalayka/bezier_fractal_2d/blob/0a9bf59609310160c7c4773de080f75ef69d1c0c/main.h#L173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest one is probably linear regression. If you wanted to determine the equation for the position of a falling object for example, you could plot its position against various functions of time and see if any give you a straight line. You'll find that $y$ vs $t^2$ is about linear, and you can determine the gravitational acceleration on earth from the slope of the line. Here's an example class experiment: https://www.laurel.k12.ky.us/userfiles/532/Classes/19164/D%20-%20Determining%20the%20Acceleration%20Due%20to%20Earths%20Gravity%20Using%20Uniformly%20Accelerated%20Motion%20in%20One%20Dimension.pdf

But you were probably looking for less trivial examples, used outside highschool physics labs. The order parameters and critical exponents of phase transitions might be an interesting non-trivial example.